# Add some data at the end of a specific line of a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to find in a file specific line and add some data at the end of the line, something like this:

```
function AddSomeData($file, $key, $value) 
{
    $content = Get-Content $file
    if ($content -match "I work very") 
    {
        $content- add at the end $value
        Set-Content $file     
    }
}

AddSomeData "settings.conf" "I work very" " hard"
```

As a result - file with changed line: *I work very hard*. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'ld do it:

```
Function AddSomeData(){
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$file,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$value
    )
    $content = get-content $file | ForEach-Object { 
        IF($_ -eq $key){"$key $value"} 
        ELSE {$_}
    }
    $content | Set-Content $file
}
```

Then just call the Function with:

```
AddSomeData settings.conf 'I work very' 'hard'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to search and replace on each line and then output to a new file. For example:

```
get-content "settings.conf" | foreach-object {
  $_ -replace 'I work very$','$0 hard'
} | out-file "settings2.conf"
```